# how to force stack to use newer version of local package

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have a package A which is build with stack producing a library. The library is used in package B (i.e. A is a dependent package listed in B's cabal file). B is build with stack as well. Consider the four cases of changes in A and use of solver on B:

1 - When A changes then B continues to use the old state of A - this   follows the guarantee of stack that a compilation always works the same way and is not influenced by changes in other programs.

2 - If the package A has a new version number, then stack build on A followed by stack build B does silently use the new version. I think this is wrong, as it violates the guarantee; it should continue to use the old version.

3 - If package A changes without a new version number and solver is run on B, packages B continues using the old state. I think this is wrong; after running solver, the guarantee does not apply and the new state should be used.

4 - if package A changes with a new version number and solver is run on B then B uses the new version. This is is correct.

I cannot understand this behavior and how version numbers and solver interact. How to control the use of a new state of a without each time bump the version number up?  Changing version numbers all the time is inconvenient if two packages are worked on in parallel; it should be sufficient to run solver to bring the changes from A into B and without running solver, the package should always recompile, independent of changes in other packages.

For development, I wish there were an (additional) flag I could use in case 2 to set for stack to build always using the newest state of the dependent packages silently (as if there would be a new version, without bumping the version number up).

Do I misunderstand the guarantee of stack build or misunderstand the behavior of stack? The code I used to test is simplistic and is on `github: git@github.com:andrewufrank/test-depProj.git`.

The question is related to previous questions I asked regarding atoms or leksahs behavior in multi-project development. I found that the issue is essentially a question of the behavior of `stack build` and must be clarified for `stack build` first.

For clarification the stack.yam of A

```
flags: {}
extra-package-dbs: []
packages:
- .
extra-deps: []
resolver: lts-8.13
```

and for B

```
flags: {}
extra-package-dbs: []
packages:
- .
- ../a
extra-deps: []
resolver: lts-8.13
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce case #1: `stack build` on your project rebuilds *b* after any change, regardless of whether the version number has changed. As far as my understanding goes, this is expected behaviour: if you list a local directory as a package location, *stack* will treat it as part of the project proper, and not as a pinned dependency -- note that there is no version number or commit hash pinning *a* in *b*'s stack.yaml. (By the way, I suggest you add both stack.yaml files to your question, in order to make the relationship between the packages easier to grasp.)

Comment: strange - i just checked: `stack build` in a, `stack build` in b - both compile. Change in `thirdFunction` the argument type to `String`, `stack build` in a goes ok. `stack build` in b should fail (wrong type) but succeeds. What is different to your procedure?

Comment: I tried again with a fresh clone. it worked as @duplode describes once. For the next  changes in a, b compiles when a is changed and it should fail. when running b, it produces the result as expected from the previous state of a. What could be the cause? Where to look further?

Comment: I did (on a different computer): clone repository. open two terminals for a and b, `stack build` in each; everything ok. edit `LibA.hs`, add a function `secondFunc` wtih no argument. `stack build` in terminal a. then call function `secondFunc` in `Main.hs` in `b/app`. save and `stack build` in b. Error is `variable not in scope` (and a was not accessed). Then bumb the version of a.cabal and do `stack build` again. No error, a is mentioned during the stack build of b (this demonstrates that no ordinary error in code exists).  is this only on my computers (all of them so) and not reproducable?

Comment: [1/2] (1) There was one difference in the steps I followed: I didn't use `stack build` in the `a` directory, only in `b` (which triggers a rebuild of *a* if necessary). Doing `stack build` in `a` beforehand seems to lead to the unexpected usage of the old version that you describe. That doesn't seem right -- I wonder if there are bug reports related to that. (2) Fortunately, I believe there is an easy workaround: always work from the `b` directory and, if you want to build/test/etc. only the *a* package, specify that when calling *stack* with, for instance, `stack build a`.

Comment: [2/2] (3) As for the version numbers, it really shouldn't be necessary to bump version numbers on every change (it would be terribly impractical and inconvenient). I suggest abandoning that part of your question, in particular because it can affect the other results we are trying to see.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug and I reported it. 
The workaround is, as described by @duplode, to do `stack build` only in one project or to use the `--force-dirty` flag when `stack-build`.

The problem is seemingly caused by behavior of cabal, which reuses an ID even when the content of a package has changed. A fix was included in stack 1.4.0. (see stack issues #2904 #3047), but it appears this was not effective in all cases.